# Matching Query from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables as the following Table1 and Table2

Table1 as the following

```
    SiteClassification |  Name1 |  ID
---------------------------------------------
    Golden                AA      23
    Platinum              BB      24
    Golden                CC      25
    Golden                DD      26
```

Table2 as the following

```
    Motor               |  Name2 |  ID
------------------------------------------
    Perkins                AB      23
    Honda                  BA      24
    Honda                  CA      25
    Suzuki                 DF      26
```

What I can't do is create a Query that show a Table with all the records from both tables where the records have the same ID.

Result Needed

```
    Motor               |  Name2 |  ID    | Name1   | SiteClassification 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Perkins                AA      23        AB          Golden
    Honda                  BB      24        BA          Platinum
    Honda                  CC      25        CA          Golden
    Suzuki                 DD      26        DF          Golden
```

I tried to use a SELECT * FROM , LEFT JOIN but I'm always getting nothing!!
can you please asist ..

regards,

Comment: `Select * from Table1 Left Join Table2 On Table1.ID = Table2.ID` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following query:-

```
SELECT table2.motor, table1.name1 AS Name2, table1.id, table2.name2 AS Name1, table1.SiteClassification
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT Motor,Name2,Table1.Id,Name1,SiteClassification FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```